# Wordpress upload path decalration

Tags: plugin-development, wp-filesystem

I am trying to use wp-filesystem to write css data.I have things working perfect here.

```
       $filepath = get_template_directory() . '/dynamic/';
       $wp_filesystem->mkdir($filepath);
```

But this generate files in theme folder. But what is if I want to generate in upload folder?

I have tried `$filepath = wp_upload_dir() . '/dynamic/`
But it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try

```
        $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
        $uploads_dir = trailingslashit($uploads['basedir']);
        $filepath = $uploads_dir . '/dynamic/';
        $wp_filesystem->mkdir($filepath);
```

It may help